# onEdit Simple Trigger not working when Publish Test as Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, add-on

I have been banging my head on this for awhile now...my document bound google app script works great when testing local to the document. I tried to test as publish > Test as Add-on with another sheet. Although my onInstall() and onOpen() simple triggers worked fine, my onEdit function did not.

I created this simple code below to find the root cause of my onEdit issue, but even this simple code does not work. I created a new sheet with a bound script. I then tested in another sheet, again the onInstall() and onOpen() worked fine, the opOpen menu even called my on Edit function, but when editing a cell nothing happens. Any help is appreciated, I would like to get this to work with simple triggers not installable triggers, as this seems like a really simple use case.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Test Menu')
    .addItem('Hello', 'onEdit')
    .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log('ran onedit!');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello');
}
```

Comment: The [Simple Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) suggest this may be intended behavior. `The script must be bound to a Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms file.` Which is why it works when Testing as an Add-on using the same spreadsheet it is bound to, but not when using a different spreadsheet. In which, an Installable Trigger would fix the issue - even if it seems like overkill. There is an [Open Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63950879) in the bug tracker you can follow.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks I must have missed this simple trigger restriction in the documentation. I implemented as an installable trigger, a little overkill but no biggy.

[Ironically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/test) "Installable triggers are currently not supported when testing. Functionality that depends on installable triggers will not be testable."

This restriction seems to make testing add-on scripts next to impossible.

```
function createTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}

function onMyEdit(e) { 
  Logger.log('ran onedit!');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello');
}
```